# git pushes with wrong user name from my terminal

Tags: linux, git

I'm having a technical issue with my git hub and web terminal. when I was starting out with configuring my GitHub through my web terminal I configured two of my git hub accounts into the shell because it wasn't working at first, then when I learned better I decided to settle for one but I didn't delete one because I didn't think it really mattered. but now my web terminal recognizes both of the accounts as masters, when I go to my GitHub repo I still see committed by the wrong username not the one I intended to use

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your git username and email
Change username & email as desired. Make it a global change or specific to the local repo:

```
git config [--global] user.name "Full Name"
git config [--global] user.email "email@address.com"
```